# Docker: correct way to restrict access to certain IP addresses

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

I have a Docker container exposing port 3306 to the Internet. I would like to restrict access to certain public IP addresses. As an example, let's use 1.2.3.4.

As an additional condition, I want the rules to survive restarting the Docker daemon and rebooting the server. This allows me to use `iptables-persistent` (`iptables-save`/`iptables-restore`) to restore the rules when the server is rebooted, without having the `dockerd` startup interfering with it.

I tried the following:

1. Modifying the `FORWARD` chain:

   ```
   iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT
   iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   This works when done after starting the Docker daemon. When restarting the daemon, Docker inserts additional rules at the top of the chain, and my custom rules end up being ignored.
2. Modifying the `DOCKER` chain:

   ```
   iptables -N DOCKER # if chain does not yet exist
   iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT
   iptables -I DOCKER -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 1.2.3.4 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   This works until `dockerd` is restarted. It looks like `dockerd` clears the `DOCKER` chain upon restart, and all the custom rules are gone.
3. Use `--iptables=false`. While this works in principle, this solution breaks the standard Docker forwarding features, and requires setting up the forwarding rules manually.

I would be surprised if there is no proper way to do this. Any ideas?

PS: I did some reading, to no avail (e.g. [Steps for limiting outside connections to docker container with iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/704643/steps-for-limiting-outside-connections-to-docker-container-with-iptables), [Docker - Exposed ports accessible from outside - iptables rules ignored](https://serverfault.com/questions/681571/docker-exposed-ports-accessible-from-outside-iptables-rules-ignored), but these questions don't seem to deal with the restarting issue.)

Answer (score 3):

I have found https://serverfault.com/a/933803/592497 to be most valuable information to be able to expose certain ports among your internal network but block to the outside. For example a database container.

The main point is that you have to use the DOCKER-USER chain as this one will not be overwritten by Docker.

This will also solve your problem to have these rules persistent after reboot or serive restart.

Answer (score 1):

***dockersd*** can be run with the option:

> --iptables=false

If not run manually but used as service it's sufficient to add or modify the following line in the configuration file ***/etc/docker/daemon.json*** :

> "iptables": false,

More detailed documentation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Comment: While this works in principle, it requires me to deal with all the forwarding manually. I'm looking for a solution where Docker manages the forwarding rules as usual, but additional custom rules are allowed on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of having as many services as possible to be routed through my nginx to be able to do internal testing and easy switching external access off, and logging. Since nginx is a perfect proxy also for any TCP connection, the only service not being tunneled through nginx for me is my sshd.

There is [this doc describing how to load-balance between many MySQL receivers](https://www.nginx.com/blog/scaling-mysql-tcp-load-balancing-nginx-plus-galera-cluster/), but the most basic config in your case should be as simple as:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 3306;
        allow  1.2.3.4;
        deny   all;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:33061;
    }
}
```

Some more details and ideas can be [found here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/). You could also add logging and many more things.

Docker param might be `-p 127.0.0.1:33061:3306` to be limited to localhost-access only.